# How do you count Distinct Customers and group by first month seen?

Tags: looker-studio

I have a series of customers over the course of the year that I need to group into two categories: New and Reoccurring.

The data roughly looks like this:

| ID | Date Seen |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | August 1, 2022 |
| 2 | August 3, 2022 |
| 2 | July 1, 2022 |
| 2 | June 1, 2022 |
| 3 | July 1, 2022 |
| 3 | August 1, 2022 |

New customers would show up on the month that we see their first record. Reoccurring would have more than 1 month logged with us.

How would I count these two groups?

So as an example above, I'd expect to see:

| Month | Trial | Returning |
| --- | --- | --- |
| August | 1 | 2 |
| July | 1 | 1 |
| June | 1 | 0 |

Edit: Per request here's a [link](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/482fc827-3a0d-43b9-94f7-62d5d4bb2ac3) to a Data Studio report with mock data.

Comment: I don't know the specifics of Google Data query language, but in SQL, you could do something like this: `SELECT ID, count(distinct(DATETIME_TRUNC(Date Seen, MONTH)))...` and any that show a count > 1 are your recurring customers.  `DATETIME_TRUNC` is a valid valid function in Google Data Studio https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/9729685

Comment: Please share a sample editable dashboard and data source sheet so that it's easy for us to work on it. tQ

Comment: @rockinfreakshow I've added a link above.

Comment: @rockinfreakshow - Assuming it was you who jumped in and got me going. If so, thank you! I'm running into an error I'm hoping you can help with the calculation formula. Just like you have, I'm comparing two date fields. However, I'm getting:

Invalid formula - Operator "=" doesn't support DATE = NUMBER. Operator "=" supports ANY = ANY.

Since they're both date fields, I'm at a loss... Any ideas?

Comment: is this a different dashboard you are trying it on. anyways try setting the date to month type at data source level and see if you can thwart the error (https://nimb.ws/HopVhk)

Comment: @rockinfreakshow - 

It is - I've been pulling over your approach to my real dashboard (which is for work, so I can't share it out). The field is set to month type, so that's not the problem. Any other ideas? Here's my version of your formula: `case when event_date (Table-1)=event_date (Table-2) then 'Trial' else 'Returning' end`

Comment: CASE() is good. based on the error message we are forcing a comparison b/w date and a number. so its most likely got to do with the field type mismatch in the backend. @Yecats

Comment: @rockinfreakshow I've narrowed it down to my Table-2 version of the event_date thinking it's not a date type. Which makes no sense since Table 1 and Table 2 are pulling from the same base data source. The raw data of the original data source (i.e. before it's blended) is also showing the calendar icon & it's type set to Date. I'm totally at a loss. :/ Any workaround ideas?

Comment: Here's a [screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16gjUvX2Bx7RSio2WglEZaQ1hUeLtzP-n/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Changing it to Month Year seems to have fixed it. Not sure why... but thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added the solution to your dashboard.
created a blend and used a calculated field to pivot the data

```
CASE WHEN Month (Table 1)=Month (Table 2) THEN 'TRIAL' ELSE 'RETURNING' END
```

[image]